# Пунктуация в предложении («Самшитовый лес»)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, определения

> Самолет взревел и затих. Люди зашевелились и стали подниматься, разминаться и потянулись к выходу(**?**) сонные, помятые.
> [Михаил Анчаров. Самшитовый лес](https://booksdaily.club/fantastika-i-fjentezi/nauchnaja-fantastika/page-26-60936-mihail-ancharov-samshitovyi-les.html)

Есть такое правило: если определение отделено от существительного другими членами предложения, то оно обособляется.
Отсутствие запятой перед словом "сонные" — это верно? Может, имеется какая-то особенность, тонкость?
Поделитесь своими знаниями (и, если есть, примерами).

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант: здесь два предложения, где во втором — прилагательные с переходом в существительные, ставшие подлежащими. *Особенность*, возможно, — в опущенной запятой (тире) между ними: «Люди зашевелились и стали подниматься, разминаться, и потянулись к выходу сонные, помятые».

Впрочем, есть примеры, удовлетворяющие обозначенному в вопросе правилу:

> Выхожу и автоматически, по привычке, достаю телефон и ставлю умный дом
> на сигнализацию — сонный еще. [Что такое геофенсинг и как настроить
> его в умном доме (2019)]
>
> Очутившись в Верхнем, он остановился, чтобы устало перевести дух,
> расставил горячие руки, словно не желая отпускать её домой, —
> неповоротливый и сонный… [Михаил Блехман. Римские цифры // «Ковчег»,
> 2012]
>
> Через минуту Юзуф очнулся, глазками хлопает, сонный. [Гузель Яхина.
> Зулейха открывает глаза (2015)]
>
> Молодой режиссер У. как-то утром открыл мне двери театра и, сонный,
> поделился открытием... [Саша Денисова. Только в Москве // «Русский
> репортер», № 45 (223), 17 ноября 2011]

Применительно к примеру, обособил бы определения не запятой, а тире: «*Люди зашевелились и стали подниматься, разминаться и потянулись к выходу — сонные, помятые*».

Comment: Интересно-интересно, спасибо! Но по-вашему получается, что в предложении все-таки есть ошибка — отсутствие знака перед вторым союзом "и". А смысл тогда такой: люди в самолете чем-то там позанимались после приземления, а к выходу потянулись только сонные и помятые? Подумаю...

Comment: Очевидно лишь, что *только* люди из числа зашевелившихся сумели подняться и размяться.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо за Ваши рассуждения. Мне тоже очень хотелось перед "сонные" поставить **знак**. Поэтому и задала вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Всё там правильно. Нашёл это правило на Грамоте, но Розенталь бы с ним поспорил. У него имеется ответ на этот вопрос:
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108 — пункт 2. 3).

*потянулись к выходу (какими?) сонными, помятыми* || Поставим запятую? Конечно нет!
А у нас просто другой падеж:
*потянулись к выходу (какие?) сонные, помятые*

Более очевидный пример: *Люди вышли пьяные.*

У Розенталя говорится про глаголы движения или состояния. "Потянулись" — глагол движения. Если поставить запятую, то будет присоединение (информация, сказанная во втором заходе), а это автору не нужно.

Comment: "Дык" у нас тут *все*, а не только "потянулись", — глаголы движения.

Comment: Ну смотрите, здесь уже дело восприятия. Можно лишь к последнему отнести. Вся фраза длинная, из-за этого мне заметно сложнее воспринять так, чтобы ко всем трём относилось. Мне кажется, что по смыслу больше подходит отнесение только к последнему глаголу. Стоп, а если И два раза повторяется, то ведь запятая перед каждым должна быть. Или присоединение через второе И сделать. Просто занимался только местом, где знак вопроса, а эту проблему не заметил, да и вы ничего не сказали. Но вариант, когда определения относятся лишь ко второму и третьему глаголу и связывают их, плохо звучит, неестественно.